# How to collect text from lines of a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a userscript that collects and displays text from the following table using javascript / jQuery:

```
<table id="table-cours">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="calendar-time"> time1 </td>
            <td>
                <div class = popup-calendar-event> popup content 1 </div>
                <div class = "link-event"> event 1 </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="calendar-time"> time2 </td>
            <td>
                <div class = popup-calendar-event> popup content 2 </div>
                <div class = "link-event"> event 2 </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="calendar-time"> time3 </td>
            <td>
                <div class = popup-calendar-event> popup content 3 </div>
                <div class = "link-event"> event 3 </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to collect all the text contained in this table except that which is contained within the `div.popup-calendar-event` elements.

My objective is to display it like this:

- **time 1** : event 1
- **time 2** : event 2
- **time 3** : event 3

The problem is that the number of lines of the table can change, here I put 3 lines but they can be 1 or 10 or any other number.

I tried many ways like using the `not()` method, or a `for()` loop with an array of "tr" elements but it never works.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, i didn't think to use find(), it is very useful ! (As you guess I am new in jQuery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('tr').each(function(data) {
  var calTime = $(this).find('.calendar-time')[0].innerHTML;
  var linkEvent = $(this).find('.link-event')[0].innerHTML;
  $("#result").append('<li><b>' + calTime + '</b> : ' + linkEvent + '</li>');
  console.log('<li><b>' + calTime + '</b> : ' + linkEvent + '</li>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table-cours">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="calendar-time">time1</td>
      <td>
        <div class=p opup-calendar-event>popup content 1</div>
        <div class="link-event">event 1</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="calendar-time">time2</td>
      <td>
        <div class=p opup-calendar-event>popup content 2</div>
        <div class="link-event">event 2</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="calendar-time">time3</td>
      <td>
        <div class=p opup-calendar-event>popup content 3</div>
        <div class="link-event">event 3</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<ul id="result"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this to parse table content and obtain an array of objects

```
var data = $('#table-cours > body > tr').map(function($i, $r) {
    var $row = $(this);
    return {
            title: $row.find('.calendar-time').text(),
            event: $row.find('.link-event').text()
    };
}).get();
```

After that you can use `data` array for whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
$(".calendar-time").each(function () {
    console.log($(this).html() + '-' + $(this).next('td').find('.link-event').html());
});
```

fiddle demo-http://jsfiddle.net/bL644p7b/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $("#table-cours .popup-calendar-event").each(function(iter, item){
        $(".result").append("<div> time "+(iter+1) +" "+ $(this).text() +"</div>");
    });
});
```

You just each a each method to iterate. The first argument is the iterator.

http://jsfiddle.net/qufgyh3c/

Answer (score 0):

```
var rows = $('#table-cours > tr');

var map = {};

rows.each(function(row){

  var key = $(row).find('td.calendar-time');
  var value = $(row).find('td > div.link-event');
  map[key]=value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".calendar-time").each(function() {
        var output = "";
        output += $(this).text() +  " : ";
        output += $(this).next().find(".link-event").text();
        $(".output").append(output);
    });
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cq772j9s/

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
$.each($('#table-cours tr'), function (i, val) {
    $('#results ul').append('<li><strong>' + $(val).find('td.calendar-time').text() + '</strong>:' + $(val).find('.link-event').text() + '</li>');
});
```

[example fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tamak/d29exk3v/)